# iOS - Reuse exact same cell design and code in multiple views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 4 different views in my app that currently display the exact same UITableViewCell. In my Storyboard I have 4 occurrences of the same cell (which is quite a complicated custom cell) and in the .m files, I have more or less the exact same code do associate the data to the UITableViewCell.

I know this is a wrong approach -- it's extremely hard to maintain and to update.

What is the right approach to centralise the UITableViewCell in the Storyboard and the centralise the code that populate the table so I can reuse it in different views?

Comment: Use xib, nothing else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to create a `Xib` file for your `UITableViewCell` subclass, with a `configuration(_:)` function declared on it. This function can take any parameter, for example a dictionary. However, you can feed a specific data model holding your parameters, a `struct` maybe or whatever data type you are using.

`ReusableTableViewCell.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ReusableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell 
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* title;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* subTitle;

/// - Parameter configuration: It is a dictionary at the minute
///                            However, it could be any type, you could even be creating your own model struct or class
- (void)configureWith:(NSDictionary *)configuration;
@end
```

`ReusableTableViewCell.m`

```
#import "ReusableTableViewCell.h"

@implementation ReusableTableViewCell

- (void)configureWith:(NSDictionary *)configuration {
    self.title.text = configuration[@"title"];
    self.subTitle.text = configuration[@"subTitle"];
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.title.text = nil;
    self.subTitle.text = nil;
}

@end
```

Register the `nib` to your `tableView`. Important, do not register it as  a `class`, register it as a `nib`.

```
[tableView registerNib: [UINib nibWithNibName:@"yourCellNibName" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"yourReuseIdentifier"];
```

And at the end in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` just simply get the configuration and feed it into your `tableViewCell`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // create your cell
    ReusableTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourReuseIdentifier"];
    // get your configuration
    NSDictionary *configuration = [configurations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //configure your cell
    [cell configureWith: configuration];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Personally I think writing all views in code is the best way to reach maximum reusability (and extensibility, since nib files can't be subclassed). But I think you might also be able to create a separate nib for the UITableViewCell and load it in each view controller. I think for either approach (designing the cell fully in code, or with help of a nib file) you would load the cell in code in `viewDidLoad`, using something like:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:MyCustomCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

*<sup>The above is what I mostly use, since I like to write all views in code, apparently for loading nibs you can refer to the method described by [dirtydanee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41408544/250164).</sup>*

Your tableView would then load the cell with the same identifier in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    // configure your cell here ...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that ! But about the "configure your cell here..." part, how can I centralise that part for reusability in different views?

Comment: I am not really sure what your use case is, but lets say you use this cell to display a person's details (name, surname, address, phone number, etc…). We could call it a `PersonCell`. And it will be populated with data from a `Person` object. In that case I would just have an `-updateWithPerson:` method on my `PersonCell`. Internally it would put all the right information on all the right labels (and other controls) and keep the code in the view controller succinct.